# Python Cron Jobs Error: urs/bin/env: bad interpreter: No such file or directory

Tags: python, mysql, cron, cpanel

I am trying to run a Python script runs every few minutes using Cron Jobs. It reads a CSV file and adds data to a MySQL table. I am using HostGators cPanel for Cron Jobs.

The full error is:

```
/bin/sh: /home3/harryv/public_html/fixturetest.py: urs/bin/env: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

My Cron Jobs command is:

```
/home3/harryv/public_html/fixturetest.py
```

If it helps at all, I have realised this isn't a typical "can't find file" error, that error would just say something similar to "No such file or directory", yet this includes a lot more, I sure that my file IS in the correct directory.

Sorry if I had made a simple mistake, I am not very experienced.

EDIT: Embarrassingly I realised that I need to add the word 'python' just before the directory in my Cron Jobs command.

Comment: (non?) obvious typos.

Answer (score 1):

The path to the `env` executable should (usually) be `/usr/bin/env`, so your shebang line should read:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```